# Detect if the main object in the photo matches any images saved in local file in flutter

Tags: flutter, image

I want to implement a feature using Flutter that allows users to take a picture of a book cover and then match it to see if there are any hive local stored photos of that book cover which user took before by using camera and will add more in the future. Want to do all this function in local without using server.

For example, I hope to be able to detect if these two images refer to one same book. What are some good methods for achieving this?

I tried to use 1) Hamming Distance,  2) image label, 3) Text Recognition to calculate the similarity between the photo and images saved in the local hive file, but accuracy is low. I am still very new to flutter, and Want to know if there is any better way to do this and increase the match accuracy.

Many thanks. [image: Photo from camera]
[image: one of local saved photo]